# Find is sequence is limited and if it's monotonic.

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have this sequence : $\frac{2n^2 +1}{n^2 +1}$ for every natural number $n>0$.

I managed to prove the the lower limit is number $1$ but I cannot figure it out how do I prove that the upper limit is number $2$. I am also having problems with proving that the sequence is monotonically increasing.

Anyone can help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that : $$\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+1}=2-\frac{1}{n^2+1}<2$$

Using this the monotony is straightforward :

$$\frac{2(n+1)^2+1}{(n+1)^2+1}=2-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2+1}>2-\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+1}$$ the sequence is thus increasing and bounded above by $2$ .

Answer (score 3):

With just a hint of division, $\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+1}$ becomes $2-\frac{1}{n^2+1}$ from which everything is much clearer.

Comment: Thank, this really helped!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**$$\frac{2n^2 +1}{n^2 +1}=\frac{2n^2+2-1}{n^2 +1}=\frac{2(n^2+1)-1}{n^2 +1}=2-\frac{1}{n^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $2n^2+1<2n^2+2$. As both numerator and denominator are strictly positive, you can use that in your sequence.